# Appending link with json value as target in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am pulling data from a rest api, and need to append one of the values to a link, which is then appended to a div. I'm able to append it with localhost, but need to have it be relative. Currently, the url is setup as `http://localhost:4000/permalink-title`, while it needs to be setup as just `/permalink-title`.

I have tried removing the `http://localhost:4000`, but this breaks the link.

```
$.getJSON("//search.url-to-api.com?q=" + q, {
 },
 function(data) {
         console.log(data);
     $.each(data.data, function(i, data) {
                 if(data.type === "Practice Area"){
                    $(".practice-area-results").append("<li class='result-item'><a href=\"localhost:4000' + data.permalink + "\">" + data.title + "</a></li>");
                    if($(".practice-area-results").val() == ''){
                        $(".practice-area-results-header, .practice-area-results").empty();
                    }
                 }
     }
}
```

Comment: @AhmadSantarissy - can you clarify? I'm able to get the data, I just can't get the link to work correctly unless the `http://localhost:4000` is in the link.

Comment: I'd recommend to send your q value in a JSON like this

`$.getJSON("//search.url-to-api.com", {
q : q
}, ...`

Comment: Why is that? I already get the values, so how does that change anything?

Comment: try changing the URL to `"./search.url-to-api.com?q="`

Comment: The api url is not the issue. I'm just not sure where to correctly escape slashes in the appended url that I'm pulling. It works in the rendered markup if I remove localhost, but not in the jquery.

Comment: My bad!! try this `$(".practice-area-results").append("<li class='result-item'><a href='localhost:4000/" + data.permalink + "'>" + data.title + "</a></li>");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140112/discussion-between-ahmad-santarissy-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

all I had to do was remove the `localhost:4000/` and keep it as `<a href=\"" + data.permalink + "\">" + data.title + "</a>`